# Unwanted blendspace bone displacement in UE4

Tags: unreal-4, skeletal-animation

[image]

My characters hands "fall off" in the blendspace between the animations.
Looking for a way to fix it, if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps needed to reproduce this problem in a new project? The better we can reproduce the problem, the more easily we can test potential solutions to be sure they solve your specific case.

Comment: I would think it's pretty straight forward. The character is modelled, rigged and animated in blender and exported with actions, so the FBX is imported to UE with all the animations as a single file. Then the idle, walk, run and springt animations is put into a blendspace.

After trying to look into it myself, I suspect that the problem might be related to my rig, but every fix just makes the problem worse.

Comment: If there were only one way to model, rig, animate, and import a character, I'd agree with you. But like many things in game development, there are many different workflows you might have used here. I notice for instance that there are no polygons that connect to the hand/wrist on one side and to the forearm on the other: the hand is its own completely separate manifold. That's not a universal setup. So there may be other non-standard things going on with this character that we can't see in this screenshot, that could be relevant to the cause of this issue.

Comment: True dat. I did some testing, and it seems like the issue is with the IKs in the rig, Unreal doesn't let me import it as is so i have to parent the IKs to a bone, I suspect that might be the problem.

Comment: If you can edit your question to walk us through your IK setup, an experienced rigger may be able to recommend alternative setups/export settings that will solve the problem.

Comment: I'll try and get it done, but I have som stuff to work on beforehand.